# Creating and running a Vbs Script VIA a windows form

Tags: vbscript, windows-forms-designer

I have a Vbs script to install network printers at my place of work. The only issue is that it needs to be hard coded with the printer and server name every time I want to use it. So as a solution I was trying to figure out if I could make a simple Windows form with a text box or drop down list that would simply push the input from there into the vb script and then run it. I can't figure out how to do this for the life of me though. Here is my VB script Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
   objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\wcprt02\S100a"
        'objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\wcprt02\L30b"

Answer (score 0):

Your options are:

1. Use WScript.Arguments to pass (a few) parameters to your script started with cscript.exe from a console (DOS Box)
2. Read the arguments from a file (maintained via the editor of your choice; or Excel if you prefer)
3. Use InputBox to gather (a few) parameters via simple dialogs/pop-ups
4. Write a .HTA application presenting a GUI for (maybe many) arguments; pass them to your code embedded as a function/sub in the .hta
5. Write a .NET Forms application presenting such a GUI; you could then shell out to your script, but why not stay in .NET and avoid the mixing of technologies?